# Spring boot starter cache working concept

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, ehcache

I have implemented spring boot starter cache using @EnableCaching annotation in main method and @Cacheable(value="allproductCache") in the service layer.

I have one doubt, is this cache is user level or application level? let suppose i add some new product and that all product list with new product should be visible to UI in productlist whoever is logged in to that application.

So for do that what i am thinking is to clear the server cached when anyone is adding a product so a fresh getallproduct request will hit and get the updated product list but i wanted to make sure that it is application level if i clear the cache using cacheManager.getCache(name).clear(); should able to clear the server cache and can be reflect to all user who are logged into the application.

Comment: You can remove cache with @CacheEvict

Comment: ya i can remove that, but my concern is that, is this cache is application level or  user session level? because i want to clear the cache once something added so that fresh request should hit and can visible the new added list to all users who are already logged in to the application

Comment: this cache is application level but if you have multiple node you can use redis,hazelcast or memcache

Comment: if you are using hibernate you have first level cache which is bound to user session.
If you open second level cache, it is application level.
If you are using Cacheable annotation with ehcache, it is application level cache

Comment: i am using mongodb and mongorepository for db quries... Ok i will use Spring-boot-starter-cache with ehcache... might that will help to update all the users once any new product added to DB.